# How to scale a dataset with a center of 100 in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Say I have a set of values like the following:

```
df$values <- c(1, 10, 5, 3, 8)
```

I want to scale this data so that the median value, 5, is 100 in the resulting index. Since 10 is twice as big as 5, its index value would be 200, etc.

How can I achieve this in R? I know about the `scale` function, but I’m struggling to base it around 100 as the center. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Do you mean `x / 5 * 100` where `x <- c(1, 10, 5, 3, 8)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function -

```
scale_to <- function(x, val) x * val/median(x)

x <- c(1, 10, 5, 3, 8)
scale_to(x, 100)
#[1]  20 200 100  60 160

scale_to(x, 200)
#[1]  40 400 200 120 320
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this function ignore NA values? My data is part of a larger df so the resulting data needs to handle NAs/keep the same number of rows.

Comment: You can add `na.rm = TRUE` in `median`